# How to handle shared classes when separating modules?

Tags: python

I decided to split up my project into several different modules. After requiring only a single file in a different project I would like to use the functionality of it even without sharing/using the all the rest, which is only loosely connected and for most parts not relevant. They are now modules added with `git submodule add`.

Some files though are now required in both modules. How would I make them available in the least intrusive way?

Before it was like that:

```
myProject
- webServices
- - DatabaseUtils.py
- - ConnectionService.py
- - DBInit.py
- - Tests.py
- - Converter.py
- - Exceptions.py
```

Now the structure is like this:

```
myProject
-pyDBUtils
- - DatabaseUtils.py
- - ConnectionService.py
- - Exceptions.py
-webServices
- - Converter.py
- - Exceptions.py
-(?)
- - DBInit.py
- - Tests.py
```

Exceptions was the easiest as it just consists of Exceptions and their definitions.
DBInit however is used in both modules, and the tests are more difficult to separate.
Is there a common approach on how these shared files should be given in order to prevent having two identical files?

Comment: Common submodule of both.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - How would that look in the folders?

Comment: Make a separate project for common files probably.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I thought about this already, but I fail to see how more submodules would solve my problem. That's why I'd like to see what's on your mind, maybe we have a different thought

Comment: Why are you using `git submodule add` then? I assumed you are referring to git modules here, not python modules.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I am refering to the different file/folder structure. I would like to know how to set it up

Comment: What is `git submodule add` about then?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I wrote my current file/folder structure. I'd like to know how you recommend it to do instead

Comment: Your file structure is fine. What do git modules have to do with your project? I understand that you want to split the python structure into packages and modules. Do you understand what `git submodule add` does?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - it clones another git repo inside your existing repo, so you can work on them separately, but still have them updated

Comment: Are your folders intended to be separate projects that will be used in different places? If not, you have absolutely no reason to use this functionality.

Comment: Don't forget to add `__init__.py` to the folders that you want to use as packages.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - at this point only `pyDBUtils` is intended to be its own sub-project. `webServices` as an `__init__.py`, for `pyDBUtils` it's intended but I'm not at this stage yet. I just don't want to add another module in the project structure as I separated them to avoid dependencies